# Image moves over the navbar on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have created a side navbar and have an image next to it. This is made in bootstrap since we are making the site responsive but the navbar and image have set width. When it's on a screen that is 22 inch the image is placed correctly but when I move it to a smaller screen the image cover some of the navbar. Could this be because the columns affect the width?

Since I have no idea where the issue is I have put it on a codepen.
http://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/vXwdEO

This is the relevant code for the issue

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="frontpage">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
                <div>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty navbarTitle"></span>
                    <h1 class="navbarTitle">BRHUB</h1>
                    <div class="navbarSplit"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="header">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt navglyph"></span>
                    <h2>MAIN NEWS</h2>
                    <div class="navbarSplit"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="header">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone navglyph"></span>
                    <h2>NOW TRENDING</h2>
                    <div class="navbarSplit"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="header">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list navglyph"></span>
                    <h2>CATEGORIES</h2>
                    <div class="navbarSplit"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="header">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil navglyph"></span>
                    <h2>REGISTER/SIGN IN</h2>
                    <div class="navbarSplit"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="header">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog navglyph"></span>
                    <h2>SETTINGS</h2>
                    <div class="navbarSplit"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="socialMedia">
                    <img class="image" src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/afd97e_1c5f5ad2a5994bf689307d48d931b320~mv2.png">
                    <img class="image" src="https://cdn.ecommnet.uk/wp-content/themes/ecommnet/library/images/twitter-icon.png">
                    <img class="image" src="http://vectorlogofree.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/25280-tumblr-letter-logo-icon-vector-icon-vector-eps.png">
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input type="search" class="searchBox">
            <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/518169-backgrounds.jpg" class="feauturedImg ">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-fixed-side {
    width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f9f9;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    visibility: visable;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.feauturedImg {
    max-width: 1760px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 700px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}

.col-md-1 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.col-md-11 {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Use col-sm-1 and col-xs-1 for smaller (screen resolution) devices.

Comment: Don't use `position: fixed`

Comment: Your elements get full width if your screens become small. Your `nav` then still has `position: fixed`. So your nav disappears.

Comment: Media query will be fine to use and control your image size at different device level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `position: fixed` you are not able to use the bootstrap grid-system.

You would be able to fix this by removing the grid, and wrap you content into a `div` which are positioned.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
    ...nav content
</nav>
<div class="page-content">
    ...page content
</div>


.page-content {
  margin-left: 160px; /* width of navigation */
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpEdWo

Answer (score 1):

I seen your CSS style to fixed the nav bar:

```
.navbar-fixed-side {
    width: 160px;
    ...
}
```

Just add `style="margin-left:160px"` to the container of your image

like this: `<div class="col-md-11" style="margin-left:160px">` to fix your image margin.

Comment: @TryingToImprove I just followed her requirement sir. :)